# New garlic growth splitting out of the main stem?

Tags: growth, garlic, stems

I can't find any advice on this online anywhere.

my original 1st,2nd and third leaves of my garlic are dying back (first leaf has died back completely), but all of a sudden I have new growth coming out the stem of the garlic (just like photo). now I've always been told that you wait for the 1st and second leaves to completely die before harvesting the garlic, but with this new growth when is the best time to harvest? do I just harvest as normal or wait for this new growth to develop?[image: new growth coming from main stalk-1st dead leaf on the left near base]

Comment: You could gently uncover the top of one bulb and gauge how large it is.

Comment: I uncovered the top and it seems to be a decent sized garlic from a top down perspective. though I don't see the bulges of the cloves yet. so I'll give them a little longer. I was more worried that this extra sprouting would be an issue to the main growth or benefit maybe?.

Comment: Unless this is happening to **all** your garlic because this one plant is also your **only** plant, I would not worry about it much.